# Space launches with video camera?

Tags: launch, camera, video

Are there any other rocket launches featuring video (selfie) cameras on the rocket than Falcon 9 and Electron?

Falcon 9 has some 5 camera and Electron has 3 camera

Comment: Already the space shuttle had a lot, you can find them on the youtube.

Comment: [Roughly how many self-viewing cameras are present in a Falcon 9 LEO mission?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19891/12102) (unanswered), and [What (the heck) is this purple donut in the video of the Falcon 9 fairing's atmospheric reentry?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37103/12102) and [How common is it for spacecraft to have “selfie” capability?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19886/12102) There are more questions specifically about spacecraft selfie capabilities, but they tend to exclude launch phase.

Comment: What does "featuring" mean? I think many, many launch vehicles have cameras, but all of them have their feeds *featured* in PR videos posted in YouTube in near-real-time. Saturn V certainly had *movie cameras* that used film that had to be developed once it was recovered from the interstages (there are Q&A about those here somewhere) but don't know if it also had video. ISRO, (and CNSA and ESA I think, but not sure) have YouTubes which have shown selfie video during launches. Perhaps it's actually common to have the video but not so common to *feature* it. let's clarify what "featuring" means.

Comment: In which case an additional question something like "Which launch was the first to carry a movie camera, and which to carry a video camera that provided launch-phase moving images" would be really interesting!

Comment: I agree but I suggest you ask that question, I dont really understand what "launch-phase moving images" means

Comment: Movies or video recorded during the launch phase of a mission, as opposed to movies or video during later phases i.e. "rocket launches"

Comment: Soyuz launcher - not at every lauch, but occasionally has on-board camera too, for example this: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=fW2EhH1xRrY. You can find more with google " soyuz lauch onboard camera video".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One such launcher would be the good old Soyuz launcher. I think this onboard launch video looks particularly nice.

Given the low cost and weight of video cameras these days, I would expect most launch vehicles to have several. Whether this footage is easily available or not is a different problem.